# Modifying data which are passed to mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, react-select

I'm passing data to a mongoose schema that look like this:

```
iceCreamType:{
label: "Strawberry"
value: "strawberry"
}
```

This data comes from a react-select component.
Now I want the data to get modified like this before sending them to the MongoDB database:

```
iceCreamType: "strawberry"
```

So I only want to send the value to MongoDB.

How can I accomplish this within the mongoose schema?

Answer (score 0):

I found no good solution for this on the frontend, so I modified the data on the backend before handing it over to mongoose. Hope that helps others.